# Function returns empty array, despite printing data

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing

I'm transitioning from Python to NodeJS and I'm having trouble understanding this behavior:

```
//import modules
const { parse } = require('csv-parse') //parsing csv
const fs = require('fs') //read from file system

//file location
const file = "filepath"

//array where data will stored
var csvData=[];
fs.createReadStream(file)
     //delimiter = ',' and ignore header by starting at line 2
    .pipe(parse({delimiter: ',', from_line: 2}))
    .on('data', function(csvrow) {
        //console.log(csvrow)
        csvData.push(csvrow)
    })

fs.createReadStream(file)

console.log(csvData)
```

If I un-comment "console.log(csvrow)", it'll print the arrays (rows) of data, so I'm assuming that csvData.push(csvRow) should normally push them all into the csvData array.

I then run the function by calling it and then print the csvData, but it returns an empty array.

I don't really understand what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're facing that issue because the method in `createReadStream` is executed asynchronously. You can use a promise like below to synchronise things. I suggest you read about Promises and async/await in javascript. I think it'll be helpful building the logic

```
 function createReadStream() {
  var csvData = [];
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    fs.createReadStream(file)
      //delimiter = ',' and ignore header by starting at line 2
      .pipe(parse({delimiter: ',', from_line: 2}))
      .on('data', function (csvrow) {
        // console.log(csvrow);
        csvData.push(csvrow);
      })
      .on('end', () => resolve(csvData));
  });
}

async function readFileAndStoreData() {
  const csvData = await createReadStream();
  console.log('csvData 2', csvData);
  // LOGIC AFTER GETTING DATA
}

readFileAndStoreData();
```

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand how it logs the data in a variable I can use? Now it prints the data in the console but even if I assign the data to a new variable, I can't use it outside of that .then() function.

Comment: You can't use it outside of then. But You can make it synchronous using await for the promise. I'm updating my sample. But I hope you understand the sample is just a sample and everything depends how you're using the sample in your code. As I sugested above please read through Promises and async/await.

Comment: In other words, everything I need to do with that data, even if there's 200 functions after that, I need to do inside the readFileAndStoreData() function?

Comment: No. You can use your functions but when you need the csvData, you can call readFileAndStoreData() function(assuming you write the logic to return csvData in readFileAndStoreData).